# How to change textbox value on select event with autocomplete (jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Why won't `#input-myBox` clear when I select an item? It seems autocomplete is preventing my `.val('')` to work so how can I workaround this?

```
$("#input-myBox").autocomplete({
    source: response,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
                var selectedObj = ui.item;
                $("#input-myBox").appendTo(".foo");
                $("#input-myBox").val('');  
    }
});
```

Comment: `#input-mybox` should be `#input-myBox`, to match your question (possibly an answer).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` stops autocomplete setting the field.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var selectedObj = ui.item;
  $("#input-myBox").appendTo(".foo");
  $("#input-myBox").val('');  
}
```

Comment: Does this call to `preventDefault()` have any other (nasty) effects?

Answer (score 9):

Also, you can use 'return false;' to stop autocomplete setting the field.

```
select: function (event, ui) { 
    var selectedObj = ui.item;        
    $("#input-myBox").appendTo(".foo");
    $("#input-myBox").val('');  
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to substitute the selected value for something else:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
  ui.item.value = substituteWord(ui.item.value);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I put ui.item.value = "12345" right before return false, "12345" does not show anywhere. Assigning this.value = "12345" on the other hand has the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Is it `#input-mybox` (lowercase b) or `#input-myBox` (uppercase b) ?

This might be your problem :)

Edit: rob beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

There is inconsistent with your code:

```
$("#input-mybox").appendTo(".foo");
$("#input-myBox").val('');
```

"#input-myBox" || "#input-mybox" ???