# MVC 4 - jQuery Autocomplete with Id and Label, saving child object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I have a textbox with a working jQuery autocomplete that allows a user to key in a PartNumber and binds with PartNumber and Id.  The autocomplete list displays the PartNumber, which is preferred however when an item is selected from autocomplete the text box is populated with the Id.

Is it possible to display the PartNumber in the text box but somehow pass the Id when the form is submitted?

**Markup**

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PartId, new { id = "parts" })
    </div>
```

**Autocomplete / jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function (request) {
            $('#parts')
                .autocomplete({
                    source: '@Url.Action("CheckPartNumber", "Part")'
                });
        })
</script>
```

**Controller - Child Object (Part)**

```
public class PartController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CheckPartNumber(string term)
    {
        var parts = new object();

        if (term.Trim().Length > 2)
        {
            parts = db.Parts
                .Where(x => x.Matchcode.Contains(term))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Matchcode)
                .Select(x => new { label = x.Matchcode, value = x.Id })
                .ToList();
        }
        else
        {

        }

        return Json(parts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Controller - Parent Object**

```
public class CountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Count count)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            count.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Counts.Add(count);
            db.SaveChanges();

            count.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            count.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            count.UsernameCreatedBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            count.UsernameModifiedBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(count);
    }
}
```

**Sample JSON / bound to AutoComplete**

```
[
{
    "label": "PartA",
    "value": "2b9bd0a4-fb90-432e-b737-e0f8b22eb71a"
},
{
    "label": "PartB",
    "value": "aa84a7b3-6e1e-4b72-ae91-faee590ce58b"
},
{
    "label": "PartC",
    "value": "0ad97869-d5f2-41bc-ac2d-895eeb406d92"
}
]
```

Comment: hi can you please explain a bit what exactly you want to display label or value?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee I would like to display the label.  But when I do this it causes error since the page needs the Id in order to save the child object.  Ideal: display the label but pass the value during form submission.  Thx

Comment: Take a hidden object and display the label to a dummy textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a hidden field for this like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function (request) {
            $('#parts')
                .autocomplete(
                {
                    source: '@Url.Action("CheckPartNumber", "Part")',
                    minLength: 3,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#hidden').val(ui.item.value);
                    }
                }
            );
        })
</script>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("parts")
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PartId, new { id = "hidden" }) 
    </div>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please provide an example of how the Hidden Field would be updated when a part is selected?

Comment: hi updated my answer, let me know if any other help is required

Comment: ANother way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285198/how-to-change-textbox-value-on-select-event-with-autocomplete-jquery-ui

Comment: Thanks - it worked.  I updated the answers with my final product.